# req.session is undefined?

Tags: node.js, session, redis, sails.js

I am trying to learn `node.js` recently. And `sails.js` looks promising.

I just setup sails project, everything works ok. except that `req.session` is `undefined`.

Here is my config:

```
module.exports.session = {
  secret: '0f18410746715474fa79f357f6dedd75',
  adapter: 'redis'
};
```

when I try to use,

```
req.session.user = 'admin'
```

I find that `req.session` is not defined.

Comment: I just solve the problem. I didn't install redis. Just sudo apt-get install redis will work.

Comment: Evan, please put this comment as the answer, more folks will see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just solve the problem. I didn't install redis. Just install redis will work.

```
sudo apt-get install redis
```